# I'm new to python and while running the code , I am getting an error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable". Can somebody help me

Tags: python

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Guava", "Kiwi","Melon"]  
i=0     
while i < len(fruits):
    if fruits([i]) == 'Guava'or fruits([i]) == 'Mango':
        i+1
        print(fruits[i])
    i+=1
```

And I'm getting this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\algo.py", line 133, in <module>
    if fruits([i]) == 'Guava'or fruits([i]) == 'Mango':
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: It's just `fruits[i]`; the parentheses make this a function call with a list as an argument, not an attempt to index a list.

Comment: `fruits([i])` should be `fruits[i]`. `()` is for calling functions, `[]` is for indexing.

Comment: For reference: [Different meanings of brackets in Python](/q/30700603/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which includes tips like asking a specific question, beyond just "Can someone help me?".

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `()` after `fruits`; that's what indicates a function call:

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Guava", "Kiwi", "Melon"]  
i = 0     
while i < len(fruits):
    if fruits[i] == 'Guava'or fruits[i] == 'Mango':
        print(fruits[i])
    i += 1
```

More simply:

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Guava", "Kiwi","Melon"]  
for f in fruits:
    if f in ('Guava', 'Mango'):
        print(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses to disambiguate expressions or for function calls. Or may be used on callable objects.

```
foo()
```

```
(1 + 9) * 3
```

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def __call__(self):
...       print(42)
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo()
42
>>>
```

But square brackets for list or dictionary access.

```
my_list[index]
my_dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer about the error in the comments, but I'll propose a simpler approach.

You can iterate over the list elements directly, which is usually recommended and makes the code simpler:

```py
fruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Guava", "Kiwi","Melon"]

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit == "Guava" or fruit == "Mango":
        print(fruit)
```

Comment: If the index is needed, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is useful.

Comment: Another improvement might be `if fruit in ("Guava", "Mango"): ...`